# Magento prevent initialization of user session at ActionController

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers, action

I want to prevent that Magento creates a *session-file* (eg sess_r8mgn8n6oep1roajrimu5ako83) under `var/session` when my **nouserAction()** gets called.

So far I tried to set the `FLAG_NO_START_SESSION`-flag, but it seems to create a session file anyway.

```
class Company_Mymodule_UserController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    /*
     * @see app/code/core/Mage/Api/Controller/Action.php
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_START_SESSION, 1); // Do not start standart session
        parent::preDispatch();
        return $this;
    }

    public function nouserAction(){
        echo "Don't create a user session at all if this action gets called!';
    }
}
```

Also in the backend under `Customers -> Online Customers` the "user" is displayed, even though it's not my intention.

Comment: $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea); might be setting the session by calling other functions, as you're getting the layout, then setting the flag after. Have you tried putting the flag before this line?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging deeper into the Magento code I realized the `pre_dispatch()`-method supports additional flags.

**Controller won't start a user session**

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);
    $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_START_SESSION, 1); // Do not start standart session
    $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_PRE_DISPATCH, 1);
    $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, 1);
    parent::preDispatch();
    return $this;
}
```

When we inspect the Magento events via `var_dump(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('frontend/events'));` we realize two important things.

1. `controller_action_predispatch`

   - Fires `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest()`
2. `controller_action_postdispatch`

   - Fires `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->saveByRequest()`

As we follow the controllers' inheritance chain (`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`) we see that the two flags `FLAG_NO_PRE_DISPATCH`/`FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH` don't dispatch the previous mentioned events and thus no user session gets started in `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor`.

Another interesting approach could be to [remove the events](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5587/26487) from the global config.